# Chromium flickering on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, chromium, nvidia-optimus

I have ubuntu 14.04 up-to-date on laptop with nVidia Optimus, so I have installed bumblebee and nvidia-352.

Everything was fine, until I temporary disabled Sync to VBlank in Compiz Config Settings Manager, but when I reenabled this setting, Chromium browser still flicker on several sites. Is there a way to fix that problem?